# How to show a hierarchical terms list in tabs

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to display a list of taxonomy terms in bootstrap tabs. 
Listing the terms as below, but need some help to assign into the tabs.

Using @dipmala 's guide, I came upto following. But still can't figure out a method to separate child terms into relevant tabs. Currently the issue is all inside the foreach loop.

```
<?php $sup_terms = get_terms("supplier_categoties", array("orderby" => "slug", "parent" => 0, "hide_empty" => false)); ?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs sup_cats" role="tablist">
<?php foreach($sup_terms as $key => $sup_term) : ?>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#<?php echo $sup_term->slug; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $sup_term->slug; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $sup_term->name; ?></a>
    </li>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".sup_cats li:first").addClass("active");
    </script>
    <?php 
        $sup_c_terms = get_terms("supplier_categoties", array("orderby" => "slug", "parent" => $sup_term->term_id, "hide_empty" => false));
        if($sup_c_terms) :
        foreach($sup_c_terms as $key => $sup_c_term) :
        $tabcontent .='<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="'.$sup_term->slug.'">';
        $tabcontent .= $sup_c_term->name;
        $tabcontent .='</div>';
        endforeach;
        endif;
        endforeach; 
    ?></ul>

<div class="tab-content sup_cats_inner">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="<?php $sup_term->slug ?>">
<?php echo $tabcontent; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.sup_cats_inner > :first-child').addClass("active");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will helpful.

```
<?php $sup_terms = get_terms("supplier_categoties", array("orderby" => "slug", "parent" => 0, "hide_empty" => false)); ?>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach($sup_terms as $key => $sup_term) : ?>
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#<?php echo $sup_term->slug; ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo $sup_term->slug; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $sup_term->name; ?></a></li>
<?php 
    $tabcontent .='  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="'.$sup_term->slug.'">...</div>'; // dynamic tab content
endforeach; ?>   </ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <?php  echo $tabcontent; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the support. I've updated the question.

Comment: Hey @JudeAinsly , can you please provide a link where I can see how its looks like and how you want it ?